# How to find slope on line that known only point and angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

How to find slope on line that known only point and angle

Image will describe more clearly

I'm wont to find the orange line slope to find point on it ( b , c , d )
suppose that A and angle are known ?

What I'm looking for is equation not explanation

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slope is given by $$\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\frac{\sin 45^\circ}{\cos 45^\circ}=\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}}=1$$

I'll note  $(x_A,y_A)$ the coordinate of $A$. Then the equation is given by
$$y=x+(y_A-x_A)$$

Comment: can I ask you about this equation y=x+(yA−xA) for what ???

Comment: the equation of the line is given by $y=x+b$ and we have to determinate $b$. But you know that $A$ is a point of the line and we know (I think) the coordinate of $A$. Then, $$y_A=x_A+b\implies b=y_A-x_A.$$ Then the equation of the line is given by $$y=x+y_A-x_A.$$ Do you understand ?

Comment: My knowladge in math is very poor but I love it ^_^ 

let me say what I have understand :

The line slope equation is given by 

`slope = By-Ay / Bx-By` so `By - Ay = slope * (Bx - Ax)`

so `By = slope * Bx - slope * Ax + Ay `

We know Ax and Ay and slope now just we wont to Compensation Bx value to get By ,,, now the new point is known ;)

Comment: yah I understand what you wont :) :) 
there is 2 way to solve this problem the first one is in my comment above The second in your comment :)

Comment: how to find the angle (orange angle) if i have 2  points A(x,y) and B(x,y) ??? I mean the angle between the line and x-axis ??

Comment: If you have $A$ and $B$ on the line only, the slope is given by $$\frac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A}$$. The angle is thus given by $$\theta=\arctan\left(\frac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A}\right)$$