# Find bisector equation using a point the bisector goes through and an angle

Tags: geometry, bisection

I am given a triangle with vertices $A=(0,0)$, $B=(-7,0)$ and $C=(0,4)$. This is a right triangle. One might think from graphing that the angle bisector cuts from point B and point $(0,2)$ but this is not the case. I am having trouble coming up with the equation of the bisector given that the bisector goes through point B and has angle of $29.7$ degrees. How does one go about find the slope for this? I know once I find the slope I can plug it into the point slope formula to get my equation. I have searched this problem on here but all I found was something that said I had to get the inverse of $tan$ and subtract this from my $29.7$ degree that I previously found but when I do this, I get something that is not even close to the correct answer.

**EDIT** I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911820/how-to-find-slope-on-line-that-known-only-point-and-angle) but I am still getting the wrong answer.

Comment: Use the [angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

$BC=\sqrt{AB^2+AC^2}$

$BC=\sqrt{(-7)^2+4^2}=\sqrt{65}$

$BCC'$ is an isosceles triangle (by construction) $\implies BC=BC'$.

$C'=(\sqrt{65}-7,0)$

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $CC'$.

$M=\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{65}-7}{2},2\right)$

[image]

Bisector $\overleftrightarrow{BM}$

$\left| \begin{array}{} x & y & 1 \\ -7 & 0 & 1 \\ \dfrac{\sqrt{65}-7}{2} & 2 & 1 \\ \end{array} \right| =0$

$4x-(\sqrt{65}+7)y+28=0$

Comment: Thanks. The corret one is square root of 65.

Answer (score 0):

This bisector is one of the two straight lines  of points which are at the same distance from line $(BC)$ and line $(BA)$.

Now the distance from point  $(x,y)$ to line $(BA)$ is just $|y|$. As to the line $(BC)$, its equation is
$$-\frac x7+\frac y4=1\iff 4x-7y+28=0,$$
so the distance from point $(x,y)$ to the hypotenuse is 
$$\frac{|4x-7y+28|}{\sqrt{4^2+(-7)^2}}=\frac{|4x-7y+28|}{\sqrt{65}}.$$
So we have to solve
$$\frac{|4x-7y+28|}{\sqrt{65}}=|y|\iff (4x-7y+28)^2=65y^2$$
and the equation of the pair of angle bisectors is
$$\bigl(4x+(\sqrt{65}-7)y+28\bigr)\bigl(4x-(\sqrt{65}+7)y+28\bigr)=0$$
The internal angle bisector has a positive $y$-intercept, so its equation is
$$4x-(\sqrt{65}+7)y+28=0.$$

*Added*: *a short approach based on geometry*:

Denote $I$ the  intersection of the angle bisector through $B$ with side $AC$ and apply the *angle bisector theorem*:
$$\frac{AI}{BA}=\frac{IC}{AC}=\frac{AI+IC}{BA+AC}=\frac 4{7+\sqrt{65}},\quad\text{so }\enspace AI=\frac{4BA}{7+\sqrt{65}}=\frac{28}{7+\sqrt{65}}.$$
Now, we have the $x$ and $y$-intercepts of the angle bisector, and there is a formula for the equation of a line given its $x$ and $y$-intercepts:
$$\frac x{-7}+\frac{7+\sqrt{65}}{28}y=1\iff -4x+(7+\sqrt{65})y=-28\iff\dotsm$$

Comment: @g.kov: I don't remember how it could happen. I suspect a copy-paste accident and not checking what I typed.  It's fixed now. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: I just realized that it's an old question. 
And looking at the typo, 
it looks like the two answers and the edit were somehow
automatically post-processed. It strangely looks like 
it was $\sqrt{\{65\}}$ and then $\{$ was misread as $2$
and $\}$ as $7$. This king of distortion is quite 
often in OCR.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Given that 
$A=(0,0)$,
$B=(-7,0)$,
$C=(0,4)$,
we don't need the approximate value in degrees of the angle $B$
to find the slope of the bisector.

The side lengths of $\triangle ABC$ can be easily found:

\begin{align}
a&=\sqrt{65}
,\quad 
b=4
,\quad 
c=7
,
\end{align}

the semiperimeter of $\triangle ABC$ is
\begin{align}
\rho&=\tfrac12(11+\sqrt{65})
,
\end{align}

the radius of the inscribed circle is
\begin{align}
r&=\tfrac12(11-\sqrt{65})
,
\end{align}

and we can apply a well-known expression
to find the exact value of the slope:

\begin{align}
\tan\tfrac\beta2&=\frac r{\rho-b}
=\tfrac14\,(\sqrt{65}-7)
,
\end{align}

so the expression of the bisector is

\begin{align}
y&=\tfrac14\,(\sqrt{65}-7)(x+7)
.
\end{align}

Answer (score -2):

$$ a=\sqrt{49+16}= \sqrt{65},\, b=4,\, c=7\,$$

Using a known formula bisector length =  Product/AM

$$d= (2 \sqrt{65}\, 7)/ (7+\sqrt{65})\approx 7.49367$$

$$ B/2=\cos^{-1} \frac{7}{d}\approx 20.9133 ^{\circ}$$

EDIT1:

Equation of bisector

$$ \frac{x}{-7}+\frac{y}{d}=1$$